# Mocking express with jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

Am pretty new to JS, but I am trying my best to learn. As it is, I am trying to mock express. Here is my base class (cut down, for testing purposes):

```
import compression from 'compression';
import express from 'express';

export default class Index{
    constructor(){}

    spawnServer(){
        console.log(express());
        let app = express();    

        app.use(STATIC_PATH, express.static('dist'));
        app.use(STATIC_PATH, express.static('public'));
        etc...
    }
}
```

And here is the test I am trying to achieve, in a separate test file...:

```
test('should invoke express once', () =>{    
     index.spawnServer();    
     expect(mockExpressFuncs().use.mock.calls.length).toBe(3);
})
```

My question is - how do I make the test override the require of the class under test - is that even possible? I want to have my Index use a mocked version of express, one that includes express() and express.require.

I did read through the documentation, and attempted something like:

```
const mockFunction = function() {
        return {
            use: useFn,
            listen: jest.fn()
        };
    };

beforeEach(() => {                    
    jest.mock('express', () => {    
        return mockFunction;
    })
    express = require('express');
});
```

But that did not work - what am I doing wrong? :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Create the mock app object and make it be returned by express module.

Then you can check how many times `app.use` have been called using either `expect(app.use.mock.calls.length).toBe(3)` or better `expect(app.use).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`

```
const app = {
  use: jest.fn(),
  listen: jest.fn()
}
jest.doMock('express', () => {
  return () => {
    return app
  }
})

test('should invoke express once', () => {
  expect(app.use).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
})
```